# How to automatically replicate CodeCommit repo to Bitbucket on-prem

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, bitbucket, cicd, aws-codecommit

I want to push changes to CodeCommit and have a Bitbucket on prem repo automatically updated as a result.

I've seen a few guides/answers on how to replicate from Bitbucket to CodeCommit, but is there any way to do the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Eventbridge to monitor repository state change events and trigger an appropriate AWS service to send the data to on premise server.

Some possibilities might be:

- Lambda function which connects to Bitbucket Rest API
- Codebuild project which does not actually build anything but loads the repository and runs a script which pushes repo to Bitbucket
- Datasync (if it is possible to copy data directly on file system level (for example, through SMB)